# How to test iOS "Rate My App" functionality

Tags: ios, app-store

I am trying to add "Rate my App" functionality to an iOS app that has not been released yet.

I have a simple function, like shown below:

```
 let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Rate Us", message: "Thanks for using <APP NAME>", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Rate <APP NAME>", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/<ITUNES CONNECT APP ID>")!)
        alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No Thanks", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "neverRate")
        alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Maybe Later", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
        alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

How can I test if this works?

My app is not submitted yet, and I want to make sure the code is working.

I get the alert and when I click on Rate Us, it redirects me to the app store:

[App Store Image Shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQQQS.png)

Error in console:

```
2016-02-24 18:38:00.302 <APP NAME>[2212:808041] _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)
2016-02-24 18:38:00.305 <APP NAME>[2212:808256] _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15)
```

I am not sure if this means the feature doesn't work or something.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just try with another appId of a live app ? I agree with the previous comment though. Have a look at https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code & nothing wrong there. Also URL you have passed is correct. It might happen than it will not work on some OS version or some particular devices.

So in that case just try this URL in place of your URL:

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=YOUR+AppID
```

This is tried & tested in 1 of my App.

**Note:**

- If you want to do testing than just place AppID of any live Application. Once you done with testing than you just need to pass AppID of your App. Thats It!

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 3):

There is an excellent library for the purpose that you are looking for. You can use iRate library. All the details can be found from the following link

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate

The library checks whether the user has reviewed for a particular version and if not it prompts the user to rate the app. The period of prompt alerts can be configured. Also the feature can be tested while development provided you have a live app in the store.

I hope this helps...

Comment: Appreciate the comments on iRate. I typically try to use very few 3rd party libraries because of support, but if I fail with this I will definitely take a closer look. iRate Seems to be quite flexible.

Comment: @toneff I dont think there is any official API to get the details of Rating. If you find one then please let me know too.